# The tags "dragon-naturallyspeaking" and "naturallyspeaking" look synonymous

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

The tags "[dragon-naturallyspeaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragon-naturallyspeaking)" and "[naturallyspeaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naturallyspeaking)" look synonymous, but I don't have enough score to make a synonym suggestion.

Comment: I prefer prefixed over non-prefixed one, who says dragon is the only naturally speaking program out there? Manual re-tagging may be more useful in this case, just to verify that everything is indeed Dragon's.

Comment: @Braiam It's probably the only product with that name, given its age. Dragon NaturallySpeaking has been around since 1997.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently someone took care of it and marked them as synonyms.